# Counting instances of text in a formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, counting, countif

I'm trying to count the amount of times certain certain text pops up in a Formula, but struggling to get it to check more than one cell. For context, the purpose is to count the amount of times a URL appears in a column, to count the amount of externally confirmable information in the sheet. My current forumla is:

```
=countif(formulatext(C2:C),CONCATENATE("*","http","*"))
```

In the instance where C2 and C3 both contain

```
=Hyperlink("[URL]","[Title]")
```

As of current, it only counts C2, Outputting "1" if C2 meets the requirement, or "0" if it doesn't, C3 onwards are ignored. It should check each cell in the column to see if it contains "http" at any stage of its forumla. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Edit: At request, [This](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1szXeeBdWIxAOV6zQxcc8vBjk4NIxvWNKM5iGbBKbnSU/edit?usp=sharing) is the whole sheet, to give further context.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FORMULATEXT` does not support arrays so you can do only:

```
=COUNTIF({FORMULATEXT(C2); FORMULATEXT(C3)}, "*http*")
```

Comment: Hmm... Issue there is that I'd have to manually input those each time, for potentially 100 different cells... If that's the case, I'll probably have to find a different solution, but thank you!

Comment: On second thought actually, I could hard code it, just stick in 150 instances of formulatext checking and let them sit there if they don't get used!